# Can I get the username in a Picketlink Logout Handler?

Tags: security, jboss, logout

I'm extending the SAML2LogOutHander to add a bit of functionality and I want to determine which user sent the logout request.  However, currently I can't seem to find a way to get this information.  Is this available?  If so, how would I retrieve it?